# git push heroku master fails with parse error - which file?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm getting a parse error when I do a git push heroku master. Heroku tells me which line and column is causing the parse error, but not which file. How do I find out which file heroku is having trouble parsing? Please advise.

```
----- package.json -----

{
  "name": "mean",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "3.8.7",
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "jade": "*",
    "stylus": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.4.x"
  }
}

----- output -----

[23:46 56] git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 259, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (242/242), done.
Writing objects: 100% (259/259), 927.54 KiB | 550.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 259 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
parse error: Expected separator between values at line 13, column 16

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:mighty-mountain-5447.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mighty-mountain-5447.git'
```

Comment: Run [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) (preferably with grunt) before committing. It should tell you if there's anything that needs to be fixed with your js.

Comment: I am using jshint. Looks fine. That's why this is so baffling. I wish they would just say which file it is having trouble with.

Answer (score 8):

Happened to me too, it was the comma I missed in the `.json` file.

You probably didn't put that comma in line 13 right away, and you commited

```
  },
```

Commit again and then push to Heroku.

Comment: My package.json is shown above. I see no missing commas in it. Do you?

Comment: There are several answers. Commit again helped! :)

Comment: Yes, I found my missed comma, but then forgot to commit it.

Answer (score 7):

I just got the same exact error. In my case the problem was in the `package.json` file because I missed the comma after I manually added "engines" to it:

```
{
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x"
    },  <-- missed this comma here

    "name": "heroku",...
```

Comment: My package.json is shown above. I see no missing commas in it. Do you?

Comment: surely not... Can you post your js file?

Answer (score 2):

What's occurred is you've committed your code to git with an error a missing colon/comma. You need to `git commit -a` before running `git push heroku master` in order to get your fix into the code being pushed to heroku.

Comment: thank you so much.. After going through a lot of answer on stackoverflow i updated my package.json and forgot to commit that to git.. your answer helped me..Thank you